# Different ways of creating javascript prototype inheritance chain

Tags: javascript, prototype-chain

```
function Parent(parentName){
  this.name = parentName;
}

Parent.prototype.printName = function(){
  console.log(this.name);
}

var p = new Parent("Parent");
console.log(p);

function Child(parentName, childName){
  Parent.call(this, parentName);
  this.name = childName; 
}

1. Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
2. Child.prototype = Parent.prototype;

var c = new Child("Parent","Child");
console.log(c);
```

Can someone tell me the difference between the above statements 1 & 2. In either way child object is able to call c.printName();

Comment: Try adding `Child.prototype.newProp = 'test';` after the above code, and then `console.log(c.newProp); console.log(p.newProp);`, and see the difference depending on whether you used statement 1 or 2. In option 1 there are two different prototype objects. In option 2 they share the same prototype object.

Comment: When i used 2nd way and added Child.prototype.new‌​Prop = 'test'; even parent object got that newProp. how did it got that property?

Comment: ok. i understood. By doing this Child.prototype.new‌‌​​Prop = 'test'; i am indirectly modifying parent prototype

Comment: Not sure if I'd say "indirectly modifying", in that both `Child.prototype` and `Parent.prototype` both refer to *the same object*. It's *directly* modifying...

Comment: To my understanding, comparing to C++ its like a pointer to a variable. modify the value of pointer will change the value of the variable it is pointing to

Comment: In that comparison, `Child.prototype` and `Parent.prototype` are *both* like pointers, and both point to the same object. (JS doesn't have pointers to *variables*, it has *references* to objects. The variable itself is like a pointer, except you can't do pointer arithmetic with it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a big difference between the 2,
one of the most confusing parts with prototypes is the fact you have prototype and **proto**.

Protoype is a special property of function objects, whenever you invoked a constructor function with the new keyword, the instance proto, will be the constructor prototype.

Object.create is method that allows you to create a new object, and specify it **proto**.

So when assigning your Child class prototype via method 1, you are giving your child **class a completely new prototype object**, that will inherit via prototype inheritance through the *proto* link, the methods of parent.
This is the preferable option, as you can make modifications to the child prototype without affecting the parent prototype, since it a different object.

On the other hand on option 2
You are assigning the same prototype for both classes, they both **reference the same object,** thus changes to child prototype will affect parent prototype, which is usually not the desired case, nor a good practice.

Example of method 1:

Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);

```js
function Parent(){
  this.x = 0;
}

Parent.prototype.add = function(n){
  this.x+= n;
  return this.x;
};

var parentInstance  = new Parent();
console.log('new Parent instance');
console.log('parentInstance.add(1): ' + parentInstance.add(1));

console.log('now letss add child, which will always add 10, to the add value');

function Child(){
    Parent.call(this);
}
console.log('setting child prototype via method 1');
console.log('Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);');
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
console.log('overriding child add function, to always add 10 to given n');
Child.prototype.add = function(n){
  this.x+= n + 10;
  return this.x;
}
var childInstance  = new Child();
console.log('new child instance');
console.log('childInstance.add(1): ' + childInstance.add(1));
console.log('yay child is working');
console.log('now lets add again to our parent instance');
console.log('parentInstance.add(1): ' + parentInstance.add(1));
console.log('yay parent is still working');
```

Example of method 2:

Child.prototype = Parent.prototype;

```js
function Parent(){
  this.x = 0;
}

Parent.prototype.add = function(n){
  this.x+= n;
  return this.x;
};

var parentInstance  = new Parent();
console.log('new Parent instance');
console.log('parentInstance.add(1): ' + parentInstance.add(1));

console.log('now letss add child, which will always add 10, to the add value');

function Child(){
    Parent.call(this);
}
console.log('setting child prototype via method 2');
console.log('Child.prototype = Parent.prototype;');
Child.prototype = Parent.prototype;
console.log('overriding child add function, to always add 10 to given n');
Child.prototype.add = function(n){
  this.x+= n + 10;
  return this.x;
}
var childInstance  = new Child();
console.log('new child instance');
console.log('childInstance.add(1): ' + childInstance.add(1));
console.log('yay child is working');
console.log('now lets add again to our parent instance');
console.log('parentInstance.add(1): ' + parentInstance.add(1));
console.log('oops we broke parent');
```

Answer (score 2):

the difference between 1 and 2 is that

1st one you are creating a new object with the specified prototype object and properties, not shared with a parent

what `Object.create(Parent.prototype)` does is it returns a **new object** with the prototypes of the parent, but the 2nd one you are just **referencing (pointing) the child prototype to the parent prototype**, so if you add a property to the child prototype say,

```
Child.prototype.age = function(){
  console.log("parent can access this method");
}
p.age();
```

the parent can access this method gets printed, for classical inheritance you would want to use the first method but there are some use cases for the second method

just to expand on this post, in my opinion the best way to do inheritance is to do

```
// parent object
var Parent = {
    firstname: "john",
    getFirstName  : function () {
        console.log(this.firstname);
    }
};


// create a child object with all the properties and methods of Parent
var child = Object.create(Parent);
// add or modify child properties
child.lastname = "doe";
child.getLastName = function () {
    console.log(this.lastname);
};


// create instances of child object
baby1 = Object.create(child);
baby1.firstname = "alice";
baby1.getFirstName();
baby1.getLastName();

// to see the prototype chain 
console.log("baby1 properties: ", baby1);
console.log("baby1 parent properties: ", baby1.__proto__);
console.log("baby1 grandpa properties: ", baby1.__proto__.__proto__);
```

very simple and no use of call or manual prototype management